# What are all the moderator-only tags?

Tags: support, meta, moderator-tags

I know the red ones are the moderator-only tags. But I would like to know all such tags?

I tried to read the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), searched the Meta SO but was not able to find the list of such tags. So far, I know following such tags

- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Surprisingly, the tag [moderator-tags](/questions/tagged/moderator-tags) (even marked in this post) doesn't have a wiki yet, I was about to create it, but was not sure, if it was meant for the same use?

Are there any more?

[Return to the FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931)

Comment: I guess status-norepro status-declined status-planned are moderator only too.

Comment: and `[featured]`, `[status-review]`, `[status-reproduced]`... they're all on the [tags page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags).

Comment: @Bart how exactly is this duplicate of that post? He didn't ask what those tags are, just for a list of those tags.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd In that it contains a full list of the tags already. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/161198

Comment: @Bart - sorry! [slap my head] :)

Comment: @rene can't vote to close this one since I already voted to close, so no hammer.

Comment: I have created a starting point @rene

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No list just yet so I took the liberty to go through all [44 tag pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) and compile the list, which consists of 11 tags in total:

- [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads)
- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)