# How to refer meta SO tag in a post on meta SO?

Tags: support, meta-tags

I had just asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144954/what-are-all-the-moderatory-only-tags#comment413601_144954) on Meta SO

[image: Original Post with tag]

I had to refer the meta tags, but the tags got referenced to the main SO site.

How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use meta-tag instead of tag:

```
[meta-tag:blah]
```

- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)
- [blah](/questions/tagged/blah)

The moderator only tags are automatically rendered in red.

It's in the [tags section of the advanced editing help.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate but have you tried searching for `meta tag` on this site :-)?

Comment: Thanks for the info !!!

Comment: I also came to know about this from the revision updated by Ben on the linked question.